# Include Require.JS (r.js build) into the Middleman build

Tags: ruby, requirejs, middleman, r.js

I work with Middleman to develop, test and build my HAML & SASS Projects.

Now I also like to work with require.js. Is there any way i could integrate the R.js build into the Middleman build?

Did you make any experience with it? How do you handle require.js in middleman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as just "running r.js" is concerned, it's pretty straightforward:

1. Save r.js into the project's root.
2. Define a custom extension (config.rb) which executes r.js after the build:

   ```
   module RequireJS
       class << self
           def registered(app)
               app.after_build do |builder|
                   exec('node r.js -o build/javascripts/app.build.js');
               end
           end
           alias :included :registered
       end
   end

   ::Middleman::Extensions.register(:requirejs, RequireJS)
   ```
3. Activate custom extension (config.rb):

   ```
   configure :build do
       …
       activate :requirejs
   end
   ```

Comment: I'd advice against using exec there, since it swaps the currently executing process with the new shell process and thus when it returns the original process returns as well. E.g. if you try this in irb: `exec "echo hello world"` you'll see that the irb process gets terminated as the echo command returns. This might cause some funny behaviour like if you wanted to run some ruby code after the exec call then those lines never get executed.. So rather use: `system 'node r.js....'`

Answer (score 3):

`r.js` can be used with [`node`](http://nodejs.org) via the command line, just like middleman. I don't know how exactly you use middleman, but incorporating another command in your workflow shouldn't be a problem. You can find [instructions on how to use `r.js`](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics) from the command line [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics).

Comment: i know how to use the command line thank you ;) There is a `middleman build` command. When i do so, i would like to incorporate the require.JS build...

Comment: That would require a plugin which unfortunately does not exists, see [this issue](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/622). You could "hack" it by using an alias in you bash profile `alias build="node r.js [...]; middleman build"`